# Error Building the project while no code errors

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, runtime-error, building

[The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3V4B.png)
it was working fine , it gives me the option to run the previous build which runs no problem.
All i did was to add a form (win app)

Comment: Restarting my laptop fixed it

Comment: The .exe itself that you were trying to compile was open at the build time. That's why restarting the machine made it work. The process that held into it just had to let it go. One useful thing on those kind of errors is to go by the task manager and kill the app if it's present in there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

According to the first and second lines of the error message, we can get that the copied file has been used by another process.

At this point we only need to open the task manager to close the related process, that is a magic.

Of course, you can also restart the computer to achieve the same effect.